# Javascript and TinyMCE (can't change .value or textarea with TinyMCE)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In a perfect world (with out TinyMCE) the following code works great:`document.myform.textarea.value += '[MY_BB_CODE]';`

With TinyMCE enabled on this page, I can't use the standard javascript. I googled around and haven't found any JAVASCRIPT-ONLY solutions that didn't require some TinyMCE plugin... I'm sure I'm not looking in the right places, but has anyone here ever come across this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,TextToAdd);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
tinyMCE.get('tinymce_id').setContent(my_new_content);
```